# Does session data stay the same across applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

Since my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389492/2535) has no feedback yet, I am breaking it apart a bit. Does the session data stay the same for multiple projects (different application pools)? Could I store the shopping cart data to the session in one project and have the shopping cart project access it?

Comment: What language / web server? To my knowledge, session is not native to HTML, and is implemented entirely by the backend webserver and server-side language(s).

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add language. @arnaud got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following forum thread it deals with same problem:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1234883.aspx

Also this post on MSDN about sharing sessions between ASP.net and Classic ASP may help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

In short you can store sessions in A Database and that would be accessible from multiple applications as well from multiple servers.

If Database access is too slow for your purposes you ca also uses [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store it in memory which would be accessible over network as well as between applications.

You can download prebuilt binary for Memcached 1.4.5 from NorthScale, follow links from this BlogPost: http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows

I also found this post on CodeProject, about Shared Sessions maybe that can help.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx

Comment: The final link looks promising. I'll post results after I have it working.

Comment: Don't try [the CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx). It doesn't work. Looking at the comments in the article, many people have problems with it and most don't have any solution.

Comment: Well then the only solution is to store session information in a place which is accessible from different application pools. So as in the answer you can use A Database or a memory caching solution (like memcached) with a custom [Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your session data is available throughout your `domain name` unless you close the browser or destroy it pro-grammatically.